Why is my state machine causing Segmentation fault?
context.h:
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum class StatusType
{
    INVALID,
    INIT,
    EXCE,
    SIZE,
};

class MsgContext;

class IStatus {
public:
    explicit IStatus(StatusType type, MsgContext& context);
    virtual ~IStatus() = default;
    StatusType GetStatusType() { return m_type; };

protected:
    MsgContext& m_context;
    StatusType m_type { StatusType::INIT };
};

template<StatusType T>
class CStatus : public IStatus {};

class MsgContext {
public:
    explicit MsgContext() = default;

    template<StatusType T>
    CStatus<T>* GetStatus()
    {
        return m_statusPtr == nullptr ? nullptr : dynamic_cast<CStatus<T>*>(m_statusPtr.get());
    }

    StatusType GetStatusType()
    {
        return m_statusPtr == nullptr ? StatusType::INVALID : m_statusPtr->GetStatusType();
    }

    void SetStatus(std::unique_ptr<IStatus> newStatusPtr)
    {
        m_statusPtr.swap(newStatusPtr);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<IStatus> m_statusPtr {nullptr};
};

template<>
class CStatus<StatusType::EXCE> : public IStatus {
public:
    using IStatus::IStatus;
    ~CStatus() = default;
    void ActionExce() { std::cout << "exce" << std::endl; };
};

template<>
class CStatus<StatusType::INIT> : public IStatus {
public:
    using IStatus::IStatus;
    ~CStatus() = default;
    void ActionInit()
    {
        std::cout << "init" << std::endl;
        cout << static_cast<uint32_t>(m_context.GetStatusType()); // Segmentation fault 
        auto newPtr = make_unique<IStatus>(CStatus<StatusType::EXCE>(StatusType::EXCE, m_context));
        m_context.SetStatus(std::move(newPtr));
    };
};

test.cpp
#include "MsgContext.h"

IStatus::IStatus(StatusType type, MsgContext& context) : m_type(type), m_context(context){
    cout << static_cast<uint32_t>(m_context.GetStatusType()) << endl;
};

int main()
{
    MsgContext ct;
    auto newPtr = make_unique<IStatus>(CStatus<StatusType::INIT>(StatusType::INIT, ct));

    ct.SetStatus(std::move(newPtr));
    ct.GetStatus<StatusType::INIT>()->ActionInit();
}

I want to complete a state machine, switch between states within states, and implement different external interfaces for each state. Above is my implementation. When executing, I get a segment error on this line:
cout << static_cast<uint32_t>(m_context.GetStatusType()); // Segmentation fault

How can I fix this?

GetStatus() returns nullptr which you then attempt to dereference. See: What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

make_unique<T>(arguments) is the same as unique_ptr<T>(new T(arguments)). This is probably the most common mistake when people start using the smart "pointers".

IStatus should probably be an abstract class. (And on a side note, "state" and "status" are not synonyms.)

Is segfault guaranteed when dereferencing null pointer
